# JMeter: Stop Thread Group after first HTTP request fails

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a mobile app, and I have a Thread Group with about 40 HTTP requests, with the first being an access token request. What I want to do is if the access token fails, skip that current thread iteration.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least 3 options:

1. You can define what action to take on sampler error on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

[image: Thread group]

2. If you need to limit this behavior to one sample add a [Result Status Action Handler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Result_Status_Action_Handler) as a child of the request
3. If you need to skip current iteration based on certain condition use [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler in combination with [If Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)